# Invalid login: 501 Could not decode user and password for AUTH PLAIN (Zoho email provider)

Tags: email, next.js, nodemailer, zoho

Locally it works perfectly but when I deploy stuff to Vercel it gives me the following error

> Invalid login: 501 Could not decode user and password for AUTH PLAIN

Is there anything I am missing?

```js
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { firstname, email, message } = req.body;
  console.log("firstname", firstname.value, message.value);
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_HOST, // smtp.zoho.eu
    secure: true,
    port: 465,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_PASS,
    },
  });

  try {
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_USER}`,
      to: `${email?.value}, ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_USER}`,
      replyTo: `${email?.value}`,
      subject: `Contact form submission from ${firstname?.value} website`,
      html: `<p>${message?.value}</p>`,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ message: "success" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message || error.toString() });
  }
}
```